# LEFT JOIN on multiple IDs

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I would like to improve my search-method on my web-app.

I got a little ticketing-system. Each ticket has an own database-entry (table: `tickets`). Each ticket can have multiple messages (table: `tickets_messages`). Each message can be sent on multiple ways (table: `messages`, `tickets_messages_mapping`).

For example:

Ticket with `ID 4` contains 2 messages (`IDs: 1 and 2`). These messages have been sent by `email` and `sms`.

Now we got the following layout (see this link for an SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07891):

```
tickets:
ID: 4
date: 2015-09-18


tickets_messages:
ID: 1
--------
ID: 2

tickets_messages_mapping:
ID: 5
TICKETMESSAGEID: 1
MESSAGEID: 15
--------
ID: 6
TICKETMESSAGEID: 2
MESSAGEID: 16

messages:
ID: 15
CONTENT: Hello
FROM: John Doe
TO: ME
GATEWAY: SMS
--------
ID: 16
CONTENT: World
FROM: JOHN DOE
TO: ME
GATEWAY: EMAIL
```

Now I would like to create a search-term where I can search for ticket-date (works), ticket-id (works) and ticket-contents (does not work):

This is my first try to get all informations and make them searchable:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ticketid, GROUP_CONCAT(tm.id) as messageid, GROUP_CONCAT(tmm.messageid) as ticketmessageid, GROUP_CONCAT(mess.content)
FROM `dia9__speedball_tickets` AS a 
LEFT JOIN dia9__speedball_tickets_messages as tm ON tm.ticketid = a.id 
LEFT JOIN dia9__speedball_tickets_messages_mapping as tmm ON tmm.ticketmessageid = tm.id
LEFT JOIN dia9__speedball_messages as mess ON tmm.ticketmessageid = mess.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

What I would like to have as the result is a list of messages assigned to this ticket-id, maybe separated by comma. In fact I would like to get rows like: ticketid, title, date, content ticketid: 1 title: Test date: 2015-09-18 content: Message1, Message2, Message3

Any ideas to solve this in mysql?

Comment: What does does not work mean? what did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: Hi,

well, I would like to get a list of messages assigned to this ticket-id, maybe separated by comma.


In fact I would like to get rows like:

ticketid, title, date, content

ticketid: 1
title: Test
date: 2015-09-18
content: Message1, Message2, Message3

Comment: Yes but what did you get? You do realize that since no one else as the schema or the data they are unable to run the query so it would be nice if you could provide more details or an sql fiddle

Comment: Hi there,

sorry  for the lack of information.
This is my result: http://d.pr/11ZTb
This is my sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07891

Comment: Thanks for updating. I thing I am still not clear about is where does the search part come into the picture? Your query does not seem to filter in any way.